# Scapy, IndexError: Layer [Dot11] not found

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, scapy

I am trying to send a HTTP response using scapy. I sniff out an request and then attempt to fabricate a response. I am basing this off the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752467/create-spoofing-http-response-in-wireless-lan-with-scapy) question. Here is the code that is causing problems:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.http import HTTPRequest
from scapy.layers.dot11 import RadioTap
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11
packets = scapy.sniff(count=30)
    for i in range(len(packets)):
        if packets[i].haslayer(HTTPRequest):
            pkt = packets[i]
            dot11_frame = RadioTap()/Dot11(
                type = "Data",
                FCfield = "from-DS",
                addr1 = pkt[scapy.Dot11].addr2,
                addr2 = pkt[scapy.Dot11].addr1,
                addr3 = pkt[scapy.Dot11].addr1,
                )
```

After I sniff the packet and get all the information required I do what the other guy did, and the problem is that I keep on getting this error with the part defining dot11_frame, `IndexError: Layer [Dot11] not found`, this happens when the line `addr1 = pkt[scapy.Dot11].addr2` is run. I have not even done a wildcard import like [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154506/scapy-dot11-not-found) answers suggested. So how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably mean `pkt[Dot11]`, not `[scapy.Dot11]`, as you imported the name `Dot11`.

Second, it seems that the packet you are capturing do not contain a `Dot11` layer. This will happen, for example, if you capture packets from a non-Wi-Fi interface, or from a Wi-Fi interface that is **not** configured as a monitor interface.

To help you debug your problem, you could add a `print(pkt.command())` just after assigning the `pkt` variable.

Also, you probably want to learn a bit of Python before using Scapy seriously. For example, rather than:

```py
for i in range(len(packets)):
    if packets[i].haslayer(HTTPRequest):
        pkt = packets[i]
        [...]
```

You want to write:

```
for pkt in packets:
    if HTTPRequest not in pkt:
        continue
    [...]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I put my network card into monitor mode, by using sniff(iface='en1', monitor=True) I end up catching no HTTP requests. Is there a way to fix that? Because when not using monitor mode I catch the HTTP request, but no Dot11, and vise versa, when using monitor mode.

Comment: I have no idea about that, sorry. This website is here to answer **programming** questions, that's what I have tried to do.